# i am new to Linux. Setting up kernal and tree first time to my system having the issue in setting up Building dependency tree

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dependencies

```
amesh@ramesh-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
libncurses-dev is already the newest version (6.2-0ubuntu2).
libncurses-dev set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.8.0-53-generic linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-53 linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-53-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.
ramesh@ramesh-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt install git fakeroot build-essential ncureses-dev xz-utils libssl-dev bc flex libel f-dev dison
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ncureses-dev
E: Unable to locate package libel
E: Unable to locate package f-dev
E: Unable to locate package dison
```

Comment: You are making common mistakes like spelling errors (`ncureses-dev`).  Are you really asking us how to fix your own typo? Advice: Check your input before hitting ENTER.

Comment: Seems clear that you are following some kind of instructions, but you have not provided a link to those instructions. Maybe the instructions are wrong. Or maybe you have failed to follow the instructions properly. We cannot know the answer since we lack those instructions.

Comment: Advice: Fix your `113 not upgraded` before you try to install anything new.

Comment: `113 not upgraded` - in addition to above, this is a clue that your package management is a mess. Are you running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before installing new software?  If you are neglecting keeping your system updated and you keep installing new software, you could really mess things up. In particular, if you don't use `sudo apt update` to update the list of available packages before performing other tasks in `apt` you run the risk of installing incompatible versions of software and landing yourself in dependency hell

Comment: If and when you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1358005/edit) and add all the information requested above, also include the distro and version of Linux you are using.

Answer (score 3):

This is because there are no packages with the names `ncureses-dev`, `libel` `f-dev`, and `dison` in the Ubuntu repositories, which you can check yourself at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=f-dev&searchon=names).

It is unclear what you want to achieve, and the question title (setting up kernel) does not seem to be relevant to the rest of the question. You should rather ask a question specifically about what you are trying to do.